# Google Hangouts docked windows

Tags: google-chrome

One thing I really like about Hangouts is that every time you get a message, that chat window's header turn green in the dock.

Similarly, the chat windows can be "minimized" to the lower part of the screen.

However this features doesn't seem to work this way in elementary OS (I've used OS X and Windows and it works that way). The windows just float around and there's no way to dock each chat window.

It's there a workaround for this?

Comment: It appears the Chrome extension is detecting the desktop environment and enabling/disabling features based on that. This is really more of a Google Chrome extension issue than an elementary OS one. :P

Answer (score 1):

I've the same problem no dockable windows, as a workaround I use to add hangout as a standalone app, using chrome app extension then each set always on top on popup windows